# Use Awk to Insert 0 padded Incrementing number in lines that contain a pattern

Tags: awk

I am trying to replace this:

The numbers at the start of the line will always be 3 digits, 0 padded, there may however be empty lines or regular sentences prior, as shown in my full example that has echo.

```
227| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

with

```
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

Here is what I have so far (this works but the number is not 0 padded):

```bash
echo -e "Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |" | awk '/^[0-9]{3}/{$0 = substr($0,1,3) "." ++i substr($0,4)} 1'
```

I think I need to add something like this 'printf("%03d\n", ++i)' but when I tried replacing ++i with this, it did not work.

Comment: What would be the expected output for a line like `12| Physics | 345 | cookies,seo |`?

Comment: Good question, The final output will be a markdown table. The numbers at the start of the line are actually a way for me to sort the results, I have a bash script that connects to multiple VMs with different benchmark tools and scores the pages, after all my processing I pipe it to sort and then use sed to remove the digits at the start of the line. If there was better multidimensional array support in Bash I would have used arrays instead. The reason I am adding the extra number with the padded 0s, is to further sort results when the scores match, based on an alternate scoring method.

Comment: oh I just realized you had a 2 digit number there, in my particular case the digits at the start will always be 3 digits because the number is put there by me and is always 0 padded. I updated the opening post to include more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution (you have plenty of choices ^^):

```
<INPUT> | 
    awk '
        BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
        /^[0-9]{3}/{$1=$1 sprintf(".%03d", NR)}
        1
    '
```

**Output**:

```
Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

Comment: The number currently at the start of the line is significant so it should be the oldnumber.newnumber I tried modifying what you shared, into my current example, but no luck yet, keep getting syntax error.

Comment: That's the goal, yes ^^

Answer (score 4):

Assumptions:

- first (numeric) field in the table has no leading/trailing white space
- first (numeric) field is made up solely of digits (no periods, no exponential/scientific notations)
- don't know in advance the number of digits in the first (numeric) field (eg, could be 1 digit, 2 digits, 7 digits, ...)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } 
      { if ($1+0==$1)                     # if 1st field is numeric
           $1=$1 sprintf(".%03d",++i)
      }
1
' sample.dat

# or as a one-liner:

awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { if ($1+0==$1) $1=$1 sprintf(".%03d",++i) } 1' sample.dat
```

This generates:

```
Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

---

If the 1st column of the table could contain spaces ...

```
$ tail sample.dat
| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
44 | Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
 55| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
 6 | Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

Modifying the `awk` script and supplying the input via stdin (to mimic OP's `echo | awk`):

```
cat sample.dat | awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } 
      { if ($1+0==$1) {
           x=$1
           gsub(/ /,"",x)
           $1=x sprintf(".%03d",++i)
        }
      }
1'
```

This generates:

```
Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
44.004| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
55.005| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
6.006| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

Comment: The if statements in this one make it more difficult to read and understand at first glance, this however is a useful answer because if I ever need to do some comparison operation it will give me an idea how to do it, so thank you.

Comment: @Jieiku what part do you find difficult?

Comment: Its mostly looking at the 1 liner, but once I looked at your broken out at example I was able to understand what it was doing.

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\|/,sprintf(".%03d|",NR))}1' file
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`sub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-sub_0028_0029-function-1) replacement (by regex pattern):

```
awk '/^[0-9]{3}/{ sub(/^[0-9]{3}/, "&."sprintf("%03d", ++i)) }1' test.txt

227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming 3 digits at the beginning and one line per entry

```
% awk '$1~/[[:digit:]]/{printf("%s.%03d", substr($0,1,3), ++x) 
    $0=substr($0,4,length($0))}1' file
Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you did there, im not sure what the $1~ does, but the rest I understand, also it seems the length argument can be ommited from the second substr

Comment: @Jieiku The `~` means regex comparison. You use it when you want to compare a field/variable with  a regular expression. You're right, omitting the last argument of `substr` takes the rest of the line, but I feel its safer (and easy) to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mentioning potentially processing the markdown in the table, ruby (or perl) is going to allow the table to be capture as a fully processable, sortable data element.

Here is an example that produces your desired output:

```
ruby  -e '
$<.read.scan(/(\A[\s\S]+?)(^\|[\s\S]+\z)/){|b1,b2|
    puts b1        # the non-table part
    data=b2.split(/\R/)  # second capture is the table part
    puts data[..1].join("\n")    # the two line header
    puts data[2..].map.with_index(1){|l, i|    # this deals with the table data
        row=l.split("|")
        ([sprintf("%s.%03d", row[0], i)]+row[1..]).join("|")
    }
}
' file
```

Or use a `split` with a look ahead instead of a multi-line regex:

```
ruby -e '
$<.read.split(/(?=^\|\s+\w+\s+\|)/,2).each_slice(2){|b1,b2|
    puts b1        # the non-table part
    data=b2.split(/\R/)  # second split is the table part
    puts data[..1].join("\n")    # the two line header
    puts data[2..].
        map{|l| l.split("|")}.
        map.with_index(1){|row, i|    
        ([sprintf("%s.%03d", row[0], i)]+row[1..]).join("|")
    }
}
' file
```

Either prints:

```
Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo 
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies 
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies
```

Here is the same but sorted by the existing first column:

```
ruby -e '
$<.read.split(/(?=^\|\s+\w+\s+\|)/,2).each_slice(2){|b1,b2|
    puts b1        # the non-table part
    data=b2.split(/\R/)  # second split is the table part
    puts data[..1].join("\n")    # the two line header
    puts data[2..].
        map{|l| l.split("|")}.       # split into cells
        sort_by{|row| row[0].to_f}.  # sort by digits in col 1
        map.with_index(1){|row, i|    
        ([sprintf("%s.%03d", row[0], i)]+row[1..]).join("|")
    }
}
' file
```

Prints:

```
Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
038.001| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies 
136.002| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies 
227.003| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo
```

Or by the third column:

```
ruby -e '
$<.read.split(/(?=^\|\s+\w+\s+\|)/,2).each_slice(2){|b1,b2|
    puts b1        # the non-table part
    data=b2.split(/\R/)  # second split is the table part
    puts data[..1].join("\n")    # the two line header
    puts data[2..].
        map{|l| l.split("|")}.       # split into cells
        sort_by{|row| row[2].to_f}.  # sort by digits in col 3
        map.with_index(1){|row, i|    
        ([sprintf("%s.%03d", row[0], i)]+row[1..]).join("|")
    }
}
' file
```

Prints:

```
Last Updated: Mar 15 2023

- Score: cumulative of benchmarking tools.
- KiB: total size of the page.
- Stats: metrics related to the page.

| Score | KiB | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo 
136.002| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies 
038.003| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

This version it's entirely agnostic to what's before the first `|`, and simply tags on the padded row number after a period (`.`), so it could be numbers, padded numbers, unicode text, or even emojis.

> ```
> mawk 'sub("[|]", sprintf(".%.3u&", NR))^_'
> ```

```
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
038.002| Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

The one above aligns the row numbers to the pipe (`|`) itself, so if there are spaces, gaps will be created. To align to the data values instead while preserving any leading spaces/tabs, try :

```
227| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
 Q | Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```

> ```
> gawk 'sub("[ \t]*[|]", sprintf(".%.3u&",NR))^_'
> ```

```
227.001| Mathematics | 9 | search,seo |
 Q.002 | Top Games | 2391 | search,seo,cookies |
136.003| Top Programming Languages | 219 | cookies |
```